# Docker Python image doesn't match with Tensorflow version

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

Im trying to create a container based on *python:3.9.18-slim-bullseye* . In my requirements there is a tensorflow package with v2.14.0.

The problem is that in [tensorflow pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/) it says it needs python >=3.9 . But when I compose up I get this error;

```
Downloading tensorflow-2.14.0-cp39-cp39- 
manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator==2.14.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 69))
Downloading tensorflow_estimator-2.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.3 kB)
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.2.1 
Requires-Python >2.6, !=3.3.*, <3.8
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow- 
intel==2.14.0 (from versions: 0.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-intel==2.14.0
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `tensorflow- 
intel==2.14.0` in your requirements.txt? It seems to only have `win_amd64` whl files [on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-intel/#files)

Comment: You have a `tensorflow-intel` in your requirements, why?